# Re-activating a button on the page after already providing response

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, button, postback

I have a button that, when clicked, responds with a newly generated csv file (code below).

```
  Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", [FILENAME DETAILS]);
  Response.Write([DATA]);
  Response.End();
```

But because the page has already responded the button becomes inactive.

I need to 're-activate' this button without a browser refresh.

**What I've Tried:**

- As a work-around, I also added `btnMyButton.Enabled = false;` on the click event in order to make it clear to the user that clicking it for a second time is not accepted (not an ideal approach).

In case of any suggestions of ajax etc, please be aware that this is within the SharePoint framework.

Answer (score 1):

Since the response is a file the browser will download, and the original html page will not be modified with the response, the solution is to disable this button with javascript. I don't see how SharePoint causes problem with that solution.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. SharePoint doesn't cause this problem, I was stating that the fact I'm working within the SharePoint framework should be taken into consideration when proposing solutions that involve ajax for example. Disabling the button is a work-around, I'm not made up with it - so +1 but not answer. Thanks again.